# Getting subpages of certain page/directory on web server

Tags: apache, webserver

I am looking for a way to view all the subpages saved in any Directory on a web Server. For example, if I have a page abc.com/directorA/directoryB, is it possible for me to somehow get all the pages and directories under this subpage? or is this only possible if the Server has something like an "index" site for that Directory?

Answer (score 0):

put in your httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/directorA"> 
    Options +Indexes 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

and its only possible if the site-admin decides to show it.
otherwise robot.txt exists for that matter because it explains also where the robot can go to. but this files are alos made by an site-admin, so its only possible for the admin to show.

Comment: thanks, but i meant this for ANY Website, i.e. a Website I am browisng online, that i, unfortunatley ;), don't have any Server config Access. i.e., if i wanted a listing of all the pages, subdirectories, etc., of say, for example, CNN.com, is that possible, just having browsing Access to it, or doing it somehow programatically, but still only from OUTSIDE the actual Server?

Comment: try to catch robot.txt from domainnames, most time they lay around in the root directory of a webpage. i think you speak german.. http://de.selfhtml.org/diverses/robots.htm
but anyway this means not you can access this directorys then. in this textfile is just written which directorys could exist and what to do for the robot to save time and infos.imagine you could stumble around in facebooks server directorys ^^

Comment: hmm, the robots.txt contains only disallows, unfortunately also "Disallow: /*?". I guess that doesnt really get me any further^^

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Visio 2013 (and perhaps older versions too).

When you select "new" file Visio's "search for online templates" you can select shapes "web site map" and "conceptual web site" per https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4w4emxp3vsptv4/Screenshot%202014-06-21%2019.04.32.png

Select "web site map", follow the wizard and enter the URL of your choice.